# keySend/onKey isn't fired in SOME androids when editText full or empty

Tags: android

I have `EditText` with `maxLength=1` and `inputType=number|textNoSuggestions` (`textNoSuggestions` doesn't popup text which could trigger `textWatcher`). I need to detect backspace when there's no text, and I need to detect onkey when editText is full (there's already 1 char)

**EditText**:

```
public class ZanyEditText extends EditText {
    private void init() {
        this.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override // hardware keyboard
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                System.out.println("onKey");
                return false;
            }
        });
        this.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                System.out.println("onTextChanged");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        return new ZanyInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs),
                true);
    }

    private class ZanyInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

        ZanyInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
            super(target, mutable);
        }

        @Override // soft keyboard
        public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println("sendKeyEvent");
            return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="SpaceLetterCode">
        <item name="android:maxLength">1</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:hint"> </item>
        <item name="android:imeOptions">actionNext</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">number|textNoSuggestions</item>
</style>
```

**layout.xml**:

```
<android.maps.api.test.com.myapplication.ZanyEditText
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    style="@style/SpaceLetterCode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Here're the test results on some random phones (all from software keyboard) :

- `no` = nothing is triggered
- anything but `no` = name of the events that trigger.

Example: When EditText already has 1 character. And I send input from software keyboard and I get only `sendKeyEvent` fired, the intersection would be `sendKeyEvent` in column `Char when full`

[image]

**Is there anything I can do to detect those events in all devices?**

**UPDATE 1**:
I made a little research about how people solve this problem. [Lyft](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.lyft.android&hl=en) app just end up with custom keyboard (I mean 11 buttons on the screen). I guess there's no solution with native keyboard.